# How to avoid running query twice - ODBC Excel (new query or editing existing query)

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I have an `ODBC` connection to an AWS `mysql` database instance. It's extremely frustrating that it appears I'm obligated by the excel UI to run the query twice.

First, I have to run the query like this:

[image]

After this runs, which returns a limited amount of rows (2nd image below), then I have to run it again to load the data into excle.

My question is, is there any possible way to skip step 1 or step 2, so that I can input my query and have it load directly into the workbook?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding the problem. You are configuring a Query Connection. The first execution returns a preview and the "Transform data" option (if you want to further tailor the query). The second execution loads it. From that point on the query is set up. It only needs configured once.

To get new/changed data, you just need to do a "Refresh All" or configure it to automatically Refresh Data when the Excel Workbook is opened.

If you are adding a Query to many workbooks you could probably setup one then code a query substitution script.

Comment: Query has to run twice, enforced by this UI. I'm asking if there's a way I can simply add sql syntax and have it load without the query having to run twice. As shown above, the query is actually having to run twice (for a new query OR for an existing query that needs to be edited). I'm familiar with the refresh functionality. Changed title to reflect the specifics.

Comment: I did a little searching and also tinkering with Excel options yesterday and was unable to find a way to disable the preview query.